# If X and Y are continuous random variables, does this imply that they are jointly continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

As far as I am aware, if $X$ and $Y$ were jointly continuous, then this implies that $X$ and $Y$ are individually continuous random variables, with densities which can derived from the joint density of $X$ & $Y$ (by computing the marginals).

Additionally, I am aware that the converse is not always true.

However, I have seen proofs in probability textbooks that state that $X$ and $Y$ are individually continuous, and then proceed to talk about the joint density of $X$ and $Y$, which implies that they are jointly continuous which I thought wasn't always necessarily true?

Is it fair to conclude that if $X$ and $Y$ are individually continuous, then they are always jointly continuous? If so, why?

Comment: How about $X\sim \mathscr{U}[0,1], B=\text{Bernoulli}(1/2) $ and $Y=BX$?

Comment: If the CDFs $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ are individually continuous, then the joint CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is also continuous.